# Power BI, get Excel Data automatically convert Date Time (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss) column to whole number

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to import excel file to Power BI Desktop, using the Get Data (Excel) feature. I have a column with a **datetime** format as you can see below:

[image: Excel Column]

When I imported the excel data to Power BI, it automatically converted the column to a different format (not datetime or text), as attached below:

[image: Imported Column]

What changes should I make in the settings to make Power BI identify this column as Datetime or Text?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can just change the column data type to the desired type after loading the excel. But it'd be great if you can set to load the column as it is

Comment: I haven’t tried but its possible that if you copy the entire column and ‘paste the values’ (found when you are trying to paste something) over it then it will clear all the float number and consider date time as text, you can then import that data in power BI and it will load as it is. Do give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You might have saved the file in .xlsb format. Just save the file in .xlsx format and Power BI will interpret the datetime format as it is in the excel file.